Can I install Gosu and use it in GitHub codespace only
Can I install Gosu and use it in GitHub codespace only, I don't want to install it into my local computer. But if using Gosu on GitHub Codespace is impossible, I must install it on my local computer.
And if possible, how can I install it into my codespace!!?
the error that I'm facing - Could not initialize SDL Video: No available video device (RuntimeError)
$ ruby game/try.rb 
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.4/gems/gosu-1.4.6/lib/gosu/swig_patches.rb:18:in `initialize': Could not initialize SDL Video: No available video device (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.4/gems/gosu-1.4.6/lib/gosu/swig_patches.rb:18:in `initialize'
        from game/try.rb:5:in `initialize'
        from game/try.rb:14:in `new'
        from game/try.rb:14:in `<main>'


Well there are several ways which you can achieve your goal in codespace:

with json file configuration
by using dockerfile file
and simply using the Ubuntu command line

I'll give you an example for the last part:

Choose your codespace and open terminal
You may not be able to simple sudo apt-get install gosu because it's not available in the standard Ubuntu repos.
Easiest way would be to download the binary as following:

sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.16/gosu-amd64"


Then change the permission mode:

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu


You are ready to go:

gosu --help
Usage: gosu user-spec command [args]
   eg: gosu tianon bash
       gosu nobody:root bash -c 'whoami && id'
       gosu 1000:1 id



thanks a lot for helping me, but it seem to run into another problem of Could not initialize SDL Video: No available video device (RuntimeError). I added the full error on the main post. Hope you can help me with this.

pls share you error logs as the plain text format not the image file

I have updated the post to have the error as plain text!

You are now going out of the topic of your actual question! You better do your own research on this, or open another issue~ But one thing is obvious: the error that you are seeing occurs when you try to run SDL based graphic application like Gosu game in environment where there is nothing to display or no any support for GUI! GitHub codespace doesn't support this by default! you need to look another tool to install to achieve your goal~

so you mean I should move to local computer to use Gosu or continue with the GitHub codespace and try to research more? because I not sure if GitHub provides tools to run SDL based graphic application.
